# apply involving array and matrix

Tags: r, apply

Suppose I have data, P, that is a 3x3x10 array and a matrix, q, that is a 10x3 matrix. A function, pv_fun, takes P[,,i] as an input and q[i,] as an input:

```
P=array(runif(90,0,1),c(3,3,10))
q=matrix(runif(30,0,1),nrow = 10)

pv.fun<-function(Prob,Prev){
  solve(diag(as.vector(Prob%*%Prev)))%*%Prob%*%diag(Prev)
}
```

This works if I specify "i"

```
pv.fun(P[,,1],q[1,])
           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.02192327 0.6626384 0.31543835
[2,] 0.52426958 0.4473938 0.02833658
[3,] 0.34857273 0.5157891 0.13563820
```

However, I would like to avoid a loop and use apply, but I can't figure out how.

If I try:
apply(P,3,pv.fun,q)

This is close, i think: I'm telling it to use the 3rd dimension of P but how to I tell 'apply' to use the 1st dimension of q?

Thanks in advance!

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `lapply()` instead of `apply()`.  The `apply()` way would work if you could use all of `q` for each iteration of `apply`, but since you need to subset `P` and `q`, that seems like a less useful strategy.

```r
P=array(runif(90,0,1),c(3,3,10))
q=matrix(runif(30,0,1),nrow = 10)

pv.fun<-function(Prob,Prev){
  solve(diag(as.vector(Prob%*%Prev)))%*%Prob%*%diag(Prev)
} 


lapply(1:nrow(q), function(i)pv.fun(P[,,i], q[i, ]))
#> [[1]]
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 0.1492837 0.2669265 0.5837899
#> [2,] 0.1502058 0.5824942 0.2673000
#> [3,] 0.1411805 0.2513680 0.6074515
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
#> [1,] 0.08494298 0.6144880 0.30056900
#> [2,] 0.03750454 0.7719693 0.19052613
#> [3,] 0.19968033 0.7864584 0.01386132
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>           [,1]      [,2]        [,3]
#> [1,] 0.4515211 0.5451417 0.003337122
#> [2,] 0.2979098 0.7018926 0.000197589
#> [3,] 0.4403383 0.5592538 0.000407891
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 0.4184959 0.04292074 0.5385834
#> [2,] 0.2976478 0.05667290 0.6456793
#> [3,] 0.4141699 0.12402696 0.4618032
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 0.4212735 0.1986239 0.3801026
#> [2,] 0.1233982 0.3057945 0.5708073
#> [3,] 0.5879795 0.1914091 0.2206114
#> 
#> [[6]]
#>           [,1]        [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 0.3336499 0.257089986 0.4092602
#> [2,] 0.6231942 0.047247936 0.3295578
#> [3,] 0.4067584 0.009297672 0.5839439
#> 
#> [[7]]
#>            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 0.05933416 0.5847652 0.3559006
#> [2,] 0.12551019 0.7238791 0.1506108
#> [3,] 0.08715145 0.6421023 0.2707463
#> 
#> [[8]]
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 0.5773402 0.1198203 0.3028394
#> [2,] 0.6856290 0.1707220 0.1436490
#> [3,] 0.2166357 0.3480572 0.4353071
#> 
#> [[9]]
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 0.3454159 0.5091042 0.1454799
#> [2,] 0.2020375 0.6085781 0.1893844
#> [3,] 0.3496506 0.5355888 0.1147606
#> 
#> [[10]]
#>             [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
#> [1,] 0.008277708 0.8252787 0.16644363
#> [2,] 0.017052752 0.9246549 0.05829239
#> [3,] 0.029653306 0.7013757 0.26897095
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>